# retain array class when operation results in 2-dimensional matrix

Tags: arrays, r, class, matrix

I have an `array` that can have one or more pages or sheets (my names for the third dimension).  I am attempting to perform operations on the `array`.  When there is only one sheet or page the result of the operation is a `matrix`.  I would like the result to be an `array`.  Is there a way to retain the class `array` even when the result of the operation has only 1 sheet or page?

Here is an example.  I would like `my.var.2` and `my.var.3` to be `array`s.  The variable `my.pages` is set to `1` here, which seems to be causing the problem.  However, `my.pages` can be `>1`.  If `my.pages <- 2` then `my.var.2` and `my.var.3` are `array`s.

```
set.seed(1234)

my.rows    <- 10
my.columns <- 4
my.pages   <- 1

my.var.1 <- array( rnorm((my.rows*my.columns*my.pages), 10, 2),
                        c(my.rows,my.columns,my.pages))
my.var.1

my.var.2 <-  2 * my.var.1[,-my.columns,]
my.var.3 <- 10 * my.var.1[,-1,]

class(my.var.2)
class(my.var.3)

my.var.2 <- as.array(my.var.2)
my.var.3 <- as.array(my.var.3)

class(my.var.2)
class(my.var.3)

my.var.2 <- as.array( 2 * my.var.1[,-my.columns,])
my.var.3 <- as.array(10 * my.var.1[,-1,]         )

class(my.var.2)
class(my.var.3)
```

The switch to `matrix` causes problems when I try to use `my.var.1` and `my.var.2` in nested `for-loop`s.

The following `if` statement seems to solve the problem, but also seems a little clunky.  Is there a more elegant solution?

```
if(my.pages == 1) {my.var.2 <- array(my.var.2, c(my.rows,(my.columns-1),my.pages))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `help([)`:

```
Usage:
     x[i, j, ... , drop = TRUE]
...
drop: For matrices and arrays.  If 'TRUE' the result is coerced to
      the lowest possible dimension (see the examples).  This only
      works for extracting elements, not for the replacement.  See
      'drop' for further details.
```

Your code, revisited:

```
set.seed(1234)

my.rows    <- 10
my.columns <- 4
my.pages   <- 1

my.var.1 <- array( rnorm((my.rows*my.columns*my.pages), 10, 2),
                        c(my.rows,my.columns,my.pages))
my.var.2 <-  2 * my.var.1[,-my.columns,,drop=FALSE]
my.var.3 <- 10 * my.var.1[,-1,,drop=FALSE]

class(my.var.2)
## [1] "array"
class(my.var.3)
## [1] "array"
```